# Memory mapped files and "soft" page faults. Unavoidable?

Tags: memory-mapped-files, page-fault, pagefile

I have two applications (processes) running under Windows XP that share data via a memory mapped file.  Despite all my efforts to eliminate per iteration memory allocations, I still get about 10 soft page faults per data transfer.  I've tried every flag there is in CreateFileMapping() and CreateFileView() and it still happens.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's just the way memory mapped files work.

If anyone there knows the O/S implementation details behind memory mapped files I would appreciate comments on the following theory:  If two processes share a memory mapped file and one process writes to it while another reads it, then the O/S marks the pages written to as invalid.  When the other process goes to read the memory areas that now belong to invalidated pages, this causes a soft page fault (by design) and the O/S knows to reload the invalidated page.  Also, the number of soft page faults is therefore directly proportional to the size of the data write.

My experiments seem to bear out the above theory.  When I share data I write one contiguous block of data.  In other words, the entire shared memory area is overwritten each time.  If I make the block bigger the number of soft page faults goes up correspondingly.  So, if my theory is true, there is nothing I can do to eliminate the soft page faults short of not using memory mapped files because that is how they work (using soft page faults to maintain page consistency).  What is ironic is that I chose to use a memory mapped file instead of a TCP socket connection because I thought it would be more efficient.

Note, if the soft page faults are harmless please note that.  I've heard that at some point if the number is excessive, the system's performance can be marred.  If soft page faults intrinsically are not significantly harmful then if anyone has any guidelines as to what number per second is "excessive" I'd like to hear that.

Thanks.

Comment: How many pages does one data transfer cross?  The memory manager will try to save RAM by not loading pages until they are referenced.  Soft page faults are used by the memory manager to catch when unloaded contents are referenced so it can load them.